# Visual Studio C# Code formatting remove superfluous empty lines?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting

Consider the following code with unnecessay empty lines:

```
static async Task DemoAsync()

{

    var d = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)

    {

        int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        int count;

        d[id] = d.TryGetValue(id, out count) ? count + 1 : 1;



        await Task.Yield();

    }

    foreach (var pair in d) Console.WriteLine(pair);

}
```

Using the formatting (Edit - Adavaanced - Format document) in Visual Studio 2019 does **not** remove these empty lines. Any setting or plugin that does this?

Comment: You can use search replace. Search for (\r\n)+, replace with \r\n, make sure pattern matching is turned on.

Comment: Who is deciding whether the empty lines are "unnecessary"? If they are, they shouldn't have been inserted in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.codemaid.net/ will help with some formatting here.